# Make Ctrl + arrows work inside neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal, putty

I'm using `PuTTY` as SSH client and `zsh` as a shell. When I just connect to a host and don't run `nvim`, I can see that control-left/right keys work correctly and send a different key from simply pressing an arrow by using `ctrl-v`:

```
# pressing ctrl-v left:
^[OD
# pressing ctrl-v ctrl-left:
^[[D
```

But when i run neovim `:terminal`, I get the same input no matter if I use control or not:

```
# pressing ctrl-v left:
^[OD
# pressing ctrl-v ctrl-left:
^[OD
```

Same thing when I just edit a file: In insert mode, `ctrl-v ctrl-left` inserts `<Left>` instead of `<C-Left>`.

This behavior is **not** reproduced with `vim8`, only with `neovim`.

The only way I managed to make it work correctly is by using `tmux` with options `terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"` and `default-terminal "screen-256color"`. However, I want to know how to make neovim correctly recognize ctrl-arrow keys without using `tmux`.

My values for `$TERM` are: `xterm` before starting nvim, `xterm-256color` inside nvim.

Comment: What is the value of environment variable `$TERM` as seen by neovim on the remote host? You can do `:echo $TERM` in nvim.  (Value should be the same as your local setting as SSH carries it over.) Also, a long shot, but does toggling the "Disable application cursor keys mode" checkbox in Putty settings under Terminal>Features make any difference? (Change, then connect.)

Comment: BTW, have you considered alternative approaches to remote file editing? E.g. using local vim/scp, mounting remote dirs with sshfs, syncing remote files to local copies (with git or rsync, for example). I know people often have issues with the model you are using so I thought I'd mention some other ways they approach the problem.

Comment: I've added info about $TERM to the question.

Comment: @BLayer Such approach won't cut it for me, because I have a remote server where I do my work, and I connect to it from various clients, some of which just happen to be Windows. I want to be able to attach/detach to my session with all terminal windows and processes at any time. Furthermore, it worked perfectly well with `tmux`, so I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work with pure nvim.

Comment: I didn't mention alternatives as a workaround for this problem just as a general suggestion. Did you try toggling that Putty setting? It alters the control sequences sent by arrow keys (which might be handled differently app-to-app/terminal) so it should at least be ruled out as a cause.

Comment: @BLayer Yes, i did try, with no success. The problem isn't exactly with with ctrl-arrow not working as expected, but more with the fact that `nvim` automatically transforms `\e[D` sequence into `\eOD` before even giving me a chance to remap it. In shell without `nvim`, I see that ctrl-left yields `\e[D`, while just left yields `\eOD`, so I can possibly map `\e[D` to something useful. But in `nvim`, they're both `\eOD`, so I can't do anything.

Comment: Yeah. That's been my understanding from the start. How apps/terminals deal with control sequences and such is all over the map. Might do A given terminal X inputs and B for terminal Y inputs. (Solution could just be to find the right TERM value...one that nvim uses as is.) That's why that setting was potentially relevant and worth trying. BTW, you read this https://neovim.io/doc/user/term.html ?? (just to confirm)

Comment: @BLayer Thanks! I've tried a lot of `$TERM` values before, but it seems I missed one. After setting `TERM=putty-256color`, I got `nvim` to yield `<s-left>/<s-right>` on ctrl-left and ctrl-right, which is still weird, but at least now I can remap them inside vimrc to `<c-left>/<c-right>`, and everything works fine afterwards.

Comment: @BLayer ..well, it almost fine. I found that when I just launch a `nvim` session, it work well, but after I detach and re-attach (I use `abduco`), arrow keys and ctrl-arrow keys become swapped. Very weird. For now, I don't have any ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately I've never heard of abduco and until/unless this is more definitively associated with neovim I don't have much more to offer. BTW, did you try it with vim? I'm not seeing that info. Whether vim works or has same issue is a good data point that you might update your answer with.

Comment: @BLayer Good point! I've tested `vim8`, and it does not have the original problem. Left and ctrl-left do send different sequences out-of-box, even with default `TERM=xterm`. I've updated my question with this. However, problem with keys being swapped after detach/reattach still exist on `vim8` as well. I've tried to swap `abduco` with `dtach`, but that didn't help, so it does not look like `abduco` bug.